# Аргумент для метода setOnClickListener()

Tags: java, android

Когда идёт обработка клика некоторой кнопки, то добавляется примерно такой код:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // код обработки клика
    }
});
```

Вопрос:
Можно ли как аргумент в метод **setOnClickListener()** подставить просто объект некоего класса, который уже применяет интерфейс **View.OnClickListener()** по определению?

Comment: Создайте класс, унаследуйте его от `View.OnClickListener`. Тогда сможете экземпляр этого класса передавать в `setOnClickListener`. Я как минимум 4 варианта знаю, как передать слушателя в `setOnClickListener`.

Comment: Наверное, вы имели ввиду не "унаследуйте его от View.OnClickListener", а "примените для него интерфейс View.OnClickListener ?

Comment: Если придираться к формулировке, то тогда уж "реализовать интерфейс `View.OnClickListener`" (:

Comment: Согласен, просто я поначалу подумал что запись типа "new View.onClickListener" значит создать экземпляр интерфейса, что по идее невозможно. В этом контексте наследование от интерфейса значило бы что это возможно. Поэтому я и уточнил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если какой-то класс уже реализует (имплементирует) OnClickListener() то вы без проблем можете передавать объект этого класса как аргумент в setOnClickListener()